# How to use hebrew with selenium on python?

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to use hebrew with selenium on a hebrew website ,but when im trying to get an href link or something which include hebrew im getting this error :

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

what i should do to make python accept hebrew?

Comment: Probably some things are not meant to be...  :)